# Jquery radio button on ASP control showing white background

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, radio-button

Im using http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/ jquery custom code for radio buttons on asp controls and the radio buttons are showing a white background.

I tried everything from - backcolor to adding css to transparent to changing the TD background and still showing a white back ground.

```
<td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblControl" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radio">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>                       
                <td>
```

here's my code and the css class is radio I tried everything from input[type="radio"] etc to .radio{
background-color:transparent}

etc.

Example below of how it looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the html result of this RadioButtonList in your browser ?

With Chrome & F12 you'll see asp.net create an html table. Try to modify in live the css attributes of html controls in order to have the expected result.
After that, you'll modify your css style sheet with the same "patch".

Enjoy

Comment: I am seeing - the table and when you say modify the attributes modify which ones exactly? little confused by your answer thank you for your time.